# Is Stack Overflow suitable as a support tool for an open-source project?

Tags: discussion, open-source

I'm thinking about running an open-source project and the absolutely crucial part of it is community support. Is Stack Overflow a suitable environment for user support?

I don't mean having an issue tracker, but something like replacement of a [Google Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Groups) group, etc... Any thought?

Comment: Probably not.  It may be able to augment one, but odds are all of the types of support issues you'll want to handle won't be acceptable questions on the SE network.  We tend to have rather high standards of what questions are acceptable, because we're not *obligated* to help people.  Support is the opposite, you want to help people even if the questions aren't great.

Comment: No, Stack Overflow is not suitable as a replacement for a forum. Stack Overflow can be *complimentary* to such a support forum, but it cannot *replace* it.